# Java - detecting memory swapping at runtime

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, jvm

I have a program and a strong suspicion that memory swapping is occuring. The reason I belive that is the case is the fact that program just hangs from time to time. When I started logging, things became even more confusing as the program started hanging on different places, with different methods being executed. 

 At this time I'm using 32-bit IBM Java with 2gb dedicated to the program, so I'm right on the edge with the memory. Change to x64 is possible but before that:

Question 1: Can I programatically detect memory swapping at runtime? Or how could I at least give myslef some hints (via logging) that swapping is occuring. 

And as of now, I dont have memory usage logs availible to me, however, if xmx is 2Gigs, that's just RAM and if memory swap occurs, would it even appear that i dont have enough memory? 

Question 2: As I think about it now, can I log the start of garbage collenction? Can I detect it at runtime? 

**EDIT:** said program exports very large amounts of data from database.

**EDIT2:** can I programatically forbid memory swapping for givem JVM?

Comment: that's an OS thing, not a java thing

Comment: /proc/swaps records such information. You may detect the swap behavior by monitoring the file. As said, memory swap is decided by OS not the application.

Comment: I hope you are aware that swapping and garbage collection are two entirely different things. An operating system will swap when it runs out of physical memory, so switching to a 64 bit JVM doesn’t change anything about the actual physical memory. Since a 64 bit JVM is capable of *using* more memory, it may even *raise* the chances of running out of physical memory.

Comment: I am aware of the difference, I mentioned the 64bit java just to avoid answers like ,,you need more ram". Right now I have program that hangs without thrownig and an error or any sign of failure. Memory swap came to my mind as low performing HDD might be the reason for those hang-ups

Comment: Hanging (or being extremely slow) without throwing can be a sign of spending too much time in GC, always managing to reclaim a small amount of memory before having to collect again, so the GC considers its operation successful, while the performance is impractical. This behavior depends on the actual GC algorithm, e.g. the CMS collector will eventually throw an OOME if it detects that it spends too much time in collecting (>98% iirc). So the [Java SE HotSpot VM Garbage Collection Tuning Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/) might be helpful…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I programatically detect memory swapping at runtime?

You can monitor in the OS how much swap is being used or how much is being written to the swap partitions. How you do this depends on yoru OS>

> if memory swap occurs, would it even appear that i dont have enough memory?

If you had enough memory no swapping would occur. Note: even if no swapping occurs it that more memory wouldn't help. Most likely you need more than just your application memory e.g. disk caching also is important.

> can I log the start of garbage collenction?

You can in another process, however you can't run anything while a stop-the-world action is occurring.

> Change to x64 is possible but before that:

Java 5.0 was the last version where I would have said may be 32-bit is best. That was ten years ago.

> program exports very large amounts of data from database.

1 GB is less than the cost of a cup of coffee these days. Even tens of GB is not much to worry about. Hundreds of GBs is getting big, and if you have a few TB you have an interesting problem. Some of my clients have 3 TB machines and they have very large amounts of data e.g. 100s TB.

I gave an old computer which hadn't been used for years to my oldest daughter and she gave it to my 8 year old daughter. It has 24 GB of memory and she uses it to mainly watch youtube videos.

> can I programatically forbid memory swapping for givem JVM?

You can lock it into memory using JNI but when a machine swaps your heap space your machine is on the edge of dying anyway.